# How to publish static websites directly in markdown with in-browser javascript-based conversion

Tags: javascript, html, browser, markdown, quarto

I want to write my pages in markdown, store it on a git hosting like github, and serve into the browser unmodified with the conversion performed with javascript, if available.

The basic reason is that I found it easier to read than HTML and lightweight, which allows me to focus on important things. At the same time, it should be viewable from local disk. So I wondered:

**Is there any markdown or browser code-feature to instruct the browser to call an external file (probably a javascript) that would render it, without the interference of browser's default html parsing for `.html` files??**

- bash/python script have a first line `#!/bin/bash`.
- html has  tags, but this requires `.html` extension like [tecme](https://github.com/susam/texme), and changing the extension is a hack.

  - Desired would be to call texme from `.md`.
- [mdwiki](http://dynalon.github.io/mdwiki/) solves this by reading a real `.md` and converting it into html dinamicly after serving the main `index.html` to the browser. This makes the sites un-indexable by search engines.

  - Desired would be to have static links to `.md` contents, if javascript is disabled, then just markdown is displayed.
- PreConvertion methods like the used in Quarto/Rstudio/toomany generates additional`.html` files with embedded css+javascript.

  - Desired is to find a way to render/convert original `.md` directly.

#### Hypothetical Result

###### Example.md (avoiding .html)

```
#!../site/main_render.js
[head.title]:# "This is my own site"
[head.author]:# "my name"
[head.something]:# "other metatags"

# Section

Some text

## subSection

Some text
```

Comment: The “conventional” method is to store the Markdown in git, then use something like GitHub Actions to serve it as HTML. I've written a how-to for Quarto [here](https://tarleb.com/posts/quarto-with-gh-pages/). This also gives you important things like sitemaps, search, etc. It's certainly possible to do what you want, but it's an uphill battle.

Comment: Hi @tarleb. Its a fairly good example. However this performs the conversion on server-side. Not in browser-side. Creating an additional HTML output. It involves to focus quite a lot on specific details of quarto&github-actions. I have edited and added a desired-result.

Comment: So, I got a downvote to the question, which has all detail-alignments required by stackoverflow. If there is something missing, then I can't tell, and the downvote doesn't help.

Comment: I actually voted to close the question, because I don't think it's a good fit for this site. As it says in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow". It's still an interesting question nonetheless, but posting it to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com or a similar site would possibly be a better choice.

Comment: The question is asking on how to implement markdown parsing (probably using javascript) from browser side. I am not asking for recommendation on best-browser or best-markdown. Its coding related. What part of the text was missunderstood so I can fix it?

Comment: I did however found hacks on this days using markdown embedded into html files using tags like `script` [see texme](https://github.com/susam/texme), but it stops being a `.md` to start being a `.html` which interferes with browser's owns html parsing of `<..>` symbols, and files like `.Rmd` can't be `.html`.

Comment: I just edited the question, to provide a more coding-descriptive approach, as my quest is.

Comment: Don't know about the javascript comments but I personally would use the `quarto` command line to do an automatic manual deploy to `netlify`.